# java binary search arraylist

Tags: java, search, binary

In school we just got introduced to the binary search algorithm. However, in our newest assignment we have to make the binary search do array lists. Can anyone help me modify this code to do arraylists instead of arrays?

```
public static Comparable[] binarySearch(Comparable[] a, int counter, Comparable b){
        int left = 0;
        int right = counter;
        while(left <= right){
            int midPoint = (left+right)/2;
            if(a[midPoint].compareTo(b) == 0){
                return b;
            }else if(a[midPoint].compareTo(b) < 0)
                left = midPoint+1;
            else
                right = midPoint-1;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Folks will be more likely to help you if you demonstrate that you've made at least some effort on your own.

Comment: Wholeheartedly agree - when homeworks, we answer only specific issues on YOUR solution attempt.

Comment: Alright my apologies. I'll remember that in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#binarySearch(java.util.List,%20T,%20java.util.Comparator)